# How to delete an EC2 instance with AWS CLI by using the EC2 tag or name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to delete an Amazon EC2 instance using name or tag using the AWS CLI.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

To terminate an instance using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234
```

See: [terminate-instances — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html)

This, however, requires the **Instance ID*.

If, instead, you want to select the instance via a Tag, then you will first need to search for the instance(s).

For example, if you are searching by the instance Name (which is actually just a Tag), use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=Foo --query Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId
```

Finally, you can combine the two queries together with:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=Foo --query Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId --output text`
```